# Windows 7 multitouch

Tags: windows-7, multi-touch

I know this is not a direct programming question (which StackExchange site would fit better?) I just ask it here as I'm not sure where to post it alternatively.

Has the driver for multi-touch on Windows 7 a specific name? Windows 7 has multi-touch support if the hardware sends specific messages and they get translated to their W7 equivalent. How is the driver sub-system named? I think it's in the context of HID devices, but is there something more explicit? I should explain it to someone and I never thought about the name of that software.

Comment: I have described it as a driver for windows 7 and not named it specifically. That was enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have described it as a driver for windows 7 and not named it specifically. Found out that there is no need to name it exactly. Hearing it is a vendor provided driver was just enough information for the audience.